# How to make a string equal a scanner and "if" statement?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm having a lot of trouble having the user input a string into the console and the specific string they typed equal an if statement. I want to input "SquareRoot" into the console and it go to the if statement, but when I type it in, nothing happens. What can I do to fix this? How do I make the user input equal to the string and the if statement? Is there something wrong with my "if" statement?

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

String SquareRoot;

System.out.println("Type 'SquareRoot' - find the square root of (x)")
SquareRoot = userInput.next();

if(SquareRoot.equals("SquareRoot")) {

    Scanner numInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number - ");
    double sR;
    sR = numInput.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The square root of " + sr + "is " + Math.sqrt(sR));
```

Comment: `squareRoot = userInput.nextLine();` (`SquareRoot` looks like a classname).

Comment: `Scanner userInput = new Scanner` - does not look correct, maybe just a typo?

Comment: Yeah, i'm sorry it was a typo. I fixed it :)

Comment: Also, you do not need to instantiate a new `Scanner` object, just re-use `userInput `

Comment: What comes after the shown code? It should be something like `} else { System.out.println("Invalid input: " + SquareRoot ); }`, so the user can see what the program detected them typing.

Comment: You don't make things "equal an if statement". You just compare things within an if statement; and this code doesn't look necessarily wrong, so how do you know it isn't being entered? What *are* you typing? Have you tried *not* using a scanner and just hard-coding the string `"SquareRoot"` into the code and running it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was mostly correct:

- You had some typos that would prevent your code compiling successfully. You 
  should consider using an IDE such as Eclipse, as it will highlight these
  kinds of issues for you as you type.
- You shouldn't create a 2nd Scanner object, reuse the existing one
- Be sure to close your Scanner when done

Here's your corrected code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String SquareRoot;

    System.out.println("Type 'SquareRoot' - find the square root of (x)");
    SquareRoot = userInput.next();

    if (SquareRoot.equals("SquareRoot"))
    {
      // You shouldn't create a new Scanner
      // Scanner numInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a number - ");
      double sR;
      // Reuse the userInput Scanner
      sR = userInput.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("The square root of " + sR + " is " + Math.sqrt(sR));
    }

    // Be sure to close your Scanner when done
    userInput.close();
  }
```

Comment: *Be sure to close your Scanner when done* not for an `System.in` inputstream,